# Inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling

I have run into an error that I have not seen before and I am not quite sure how to go about fixing it. I am currently trying to make a sorting class which compares the gradepoints inside an array, I'll add that if it would help, and I have run into this error.

```
  required: Course[]
  found: Course[]
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: Course
    bound(s): Comparable<Course>
  where Course is a type-variable:
    Course extends Comparable<Course> declared in method<Course>SelectionSort(Course[])
```

The class that is generating this error:

```
public class Sorting
{
    private static <Course> void swap(Course[] arr, int i, int j)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            Course temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    //Sort method
    public <Course extends Comparable<Course>> void SelectionSort(Course[] arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            int min = i;
            for(int scan = i + 1; scan < arr.length; scan++)
            {
                if(arr[scan].compareTo(arr[min]) <= 0)
                    min = scan;
            }
            swap(arr,i,min);
        }
    }//end Sorting  
}//end class Sorting
```

Not sure how to deal with something like this, it was an old assignment that I had to do, but I couldn't get it figured out.

Test class:

```
public class Test1{

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Course[] courses = new Course[7];
    Sorting sort = new Sorting();
    courses[0] = new CSInfo("CS1083", "A+", 4);
    courses[1] = new CSInfo("CS1073", "A-", 4);
    courses[3] = new MathStat("MATH1003", "C+", 3);
    courses[4] = new MathStat("MATH1013", "B-", 3);
    courses[5] = new CSInfo("CS2053", "B-", 4);
    courses[6] = new Breadth("POLS2101", "A-", 3);

    courses[0].getPoints();
    courses[1].getPoints();
    //courses[2].getPoints();
    courses[3].getPoints();
    courses[4].getPoints();
    courses[5].getPoints();
    courses[6].getPoints();

    courses[0].toString();

    sort.SelectionSort(courses);

    }
```

}

Comment: Do you use those generic methods with a class `Course` that does not implement `Comparable<Course>`?

Comment: Well that was a dumb mistake... But now i'm running into a nullpointer exception in the same class on line 23

    if(arr[scan].compareTo(arr[min]) <= 0

Comment: @Afatmunky how do you initialize the `arr`?

Comment: @Xokker I thought that's what I was doing with Course[] arr in the parameters. I'm pretty new to this...

Comment: @Afatmunky no, `SelectionSort` sorts already initialized array. Therefore, it should be initialized outside the method. For example, `Course[] arr = new Course[] {new Course(1, "Bla bla 101"), new Course(2, "Foo Bar 110")}`.

Comment: @Afatmunky by the way, looks like you don't need generics here. In your code, `Course` is the name of the type parameter, not class itself. It may be reasonable just use following signatures: `private static void swap(Course[] arr, int i, int j)` and `public void SelectionSort(Course[] arr)`

Comment: I will try that :) and I added in the test class where I am initializing the array, if that's what you meant. I am not getting errors inside my sorting class anymore, but when I try and run it with the test class I get the nullpointerexception which points to the sorting class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you doesn't have initialized the array members, the array is ok because the nullpointer isn't in the for loop (arr.length)